# Somar valores em vetor e retornar o valor na condição verdadeira

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com uma duvida em um script onde estou fazendo um Quiz, em meu último Quiz meu eu coloquei 3 opções de resposta: A, B e C. Onde se a resposta for A soma 3 pontos para opção X, 2 pontos para opção Y e 1 ponto para Opção Z. Se a resposta for B soma 2 pontos para opção X, 3 pontos para opção Y e 1 ponto para Opção Z. Se a resposta for C soma 1 ponto para opção X, 2 pontos para opção Y e 3 pontos para Opção Z.

Então a função verifica qual Opção tem mais pontos e retorna ela.

Porém eu quero modificar para a seguinte função:

Se resposta for A soma 4 pontos. Se resposta for B soma 2 pontos. Se resposta for C soma 0 pontos.

Se a quantidade de pontos for até 10 retorna Opção X. Se a quantidade de pontos for de 11 até 24 retorna opção Y. Se a quantidade de pontos for maior que 24 retorna a Opção Z.

Segue parte do código:

```
self.jobs = [
    {
        title: 'Opção X',
        description: 'Descrição Opção X'
    },
    {
        title: 'Opção Y',
        description: 'Descrição Opção Y'
    },
    {
        title: 'Opção Z',
        description: 'Descrição Opção Z'
    }
    ];

self.job = 9999;

self.questions = [
    {
        text: 'Pergunta 1',
        answered: false,
        skipped: false,
        answers: [
            {
                text: 'A',
                selected: false,
                values: [3, 2, 1]
            },
            {
                text: 'B',
                selected: false,
                values: [2, 3, 1]
            },
            {
                text: 'C',
                selected: false,
                values: [1, 2, 3]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: 'Pergunta 2',
        answered: false,
        skipped: false,
        answers: [
            {
                text: 'A',
                selected: false,
                values: [3, 2, 1]
            },
            {
                text: 'B',
                selected: false,
                values: [2, 3, 1]
            },
            {
                text: 'C',
                selected: false,
                values: [1, 2, 3]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: 'Pergunta 3',
        answered: false,
        skipped: false,
        answers: [
            {
                text: 'A',
                selected: false,
                values: [3, 2, 1]
            },
            {
                text: 'B',
                selected: false,
                values: [2, 3, 1]
            },
            {
                text: 'C',
                selected: false,
                values: [1, 2, 3]
            }
        ]
    }
];

self.index = 0;

self.userAnswers = [];

self.error = false;

self.answerQuestion = function(elem) {
    self.userAnswers[self.index] = elem.answer;
    self.index = elem.$parent.$index + 1;

    var question = elem.$parent.question;
    question.answered = true;

    angular.forEach(question.answers, function(answer) {
        answer.selected = false;
    });

    elem.answer.selected = true;
};

self.changeQuestion = function(elem) {
    var question = self.questions[self.index];
    if(question && !question.answered)
        question.skipped = true;

    self.index = elem.$index;
};

self.goToResult = function() {
    var question = self.questions[self.index];
    if(question && !question.answered)
        question.skipped = true;

    self.index = self.questions.length;
}

self.viewResult = function() {
    var hasError = false;

    angular.forEach(self.questions, function(question) {
        if(!question.answered) {
            hasError = true;
            question.skipped = true;
        }
    });

    if(hasError) {
        self.error = true;

        $timeout(function() {
            self.error = false;
        }, 2000);

        return false;
    }

    self.showQuiz = false;

    var result = getResult();
    self.job = result;
};

getResult = function() {
    var results = [0, 0, 0];
    var maior = -9999;
    var iMaior = 0;

    angular.forEach(self.userAnswers, function(answer) {
        for(var i=0; i < self.jobs.length; i++) {
            results[i] += answer.values[i];
        }
    });

    for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var result = results[i];
        if(result > maior) {
            maior = result;
            iMaior = i;
        }
    }

    return iMaior;
};
}]);
```

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema do valor de cada letra, deve-se alterar os arrays **[3, 2, 1]**, **[2, 3, 1]** e **[1, 2, 3]** para **[4, 2, 0]**, **[2, 4, 0]** e **[0, 2, 4]** (respectivamente e nas 3 perguntas).
A pontuação você testa na função "getResult", modificando o final dela:

```
getResult = function() {
    var results = [0, 0, 0];
    var soma = 0;

    angular.forEach(self.userAnswers, function(answer) {
        for(var i=0; i < self.jobs.length; i++) {
            results[i] += answer.values[i];
        }
    });

    for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
        soma += results[i];
    }

    if (soma > 24)
        return 2; // Z
    else if (soma >= 11 && soma <= 24)
        return 1; // Y
    else
        return 0; // X
};
```

Imagino que seja isso!